# How do I solve the inverse sin without a inverse sin button with the equation $x = \sin^{-1}(0.5)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I am writing an expression in code where I am solving the angle where I know the Opposite $(2.5)$ and Hypotenuse $(5.0)$ and want to solve the angle. However, I do not have the inverse sin available. How do I solve the following equation without using the inverse sin function?

$$ x = \sin^{-1}(0.5) $$

I know that $x$ will be $30^\circ$, I don't know how to solve the equation without the inverse sin function.

Comment: You would need to create the inverse sine function.  You can write your equation as $0.5=\sin (x)$ and solve it numerically.  You might want to store a table of sines and do a search through it before using a linear approximation.

Comment: You should have a guide of special triangles. Strong hint: 30-60-90.

Comment: You could use [this Lagrange Inversion Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) to find a series representation of the inverse sine without using the inverse sine. Then, you need to find the partial sum formula and take the limit as the upper sum bounds tends to $\infty$ or you can just guess and check.

Comment: "I know that x will be 30∘"  Then you know that is the answer.  It's as simple as that.  You are being asked "what angle is it that has a sine of $\frac 12$" and it is one of the basic fundamental angles of trig.

Comment: You don't have a $\sin^{-1}$ button but you have a $\sin$ button.  Guess the answer is $30^\circ$ and punch in $\sin 30^\circ$ and once you verify that $\sin 30^\circ = \frac 12$ you are done.  If you want to say more verify by geometry that a $30-60-90$ triangle must be half an equiateral triangle so $\sin 30^\circ$ *must* be $\frac 12$.  There's not *algebraic* way to solve $\sin^{-1}$ (or $\sin$) but if you can verify certain equations that is enough.  If someway or another you know that $\sin 30=\frac 12$ that is *all* you need to assert $\sin^{-1}\frac 12 = 30$.

Comment: The Opposite and Hypotenuse will be a variable value I was using an known equation so I could apply it when I use a variable values

Comment: Please [edit] the question to tell us what language you are coding in. Are you sure there is no arcsin?

Comment: Thanks Ethan. I was am using Maya's expression and I found it under asin.

Answer (score 1):

"I know that x will be 30∘, I don't know how to solve the equation without the inverse sin function."

You *can't* solve $\sin$ or $\sin^{-1}$ equations algebraically.  But you can *know* and verify the answers.

It's enough to say: "Because $\sin 30^\circ = \frac 12$ and $-90 \le 30 \le 90$, and because $\sin^{-1} \frac 12$ is, *by definition*, the angle $\theta$ so that $-90 \le \theta \le 90$ and $\sin \theta = \frac 12$, that angle must be $30^\circ$.  So $\sin^{-1}(\frac 12) = 30^\circ$"